# Logging into Instagram in Java HttpClient 4.4

Tags: java, http, cookies, httpclient

Made some progress on my project but ran into an error. I'm trying to use HttpClient to login Instagram sending post parameters to the form but basically every time I try accessing webpage I get this:

```
This page could not be loaded. If you have cookies disabled in your browser, or you are browsing in Private Mode, please try enabling cookies or turning off Private Mode, and then retrying your action.
```

The code is as follows:

```
    RequestConfig globalConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.BEST_MATCH).build();
    CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
    HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();
    context.setCookieStore(cookieStore);
    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultRequestConfig(globalConfig).setDefaultCookieStore(cookieStore).build();
```

Update: I used this as reference 
https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientFormLogin.java

But Im still getting same problem as before. It seems to be getting cookies though?

```
Login form get: HTTP/1.1 403 FORBIDDEN
Post logon cookies:
- [version: 0][name: csrftoken][value: 85186441706764e44d9efeb6fb14acdd]   [domain: instagram.com][path: /][expiry: Wed May 18 18:05:50 EDT 2016]
```

Comment: try monitor http traffic, and see what's the difference when logging in from browser and from your code.

Comment: Explain? dont see how that will help. I found this http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/statemgmt.html#d4e777 but no idea how to implement it. Which code in which section do I use @bayou.io .@MadProgrammer help please :3 You're java god

Comment: I updated main post :3 please read